# How to destructure Javascript/Typescript variables inside of a try/catch block

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider that you're assigning values to variables when using destructuring an object *inside of a try/catch block* in Javascript. We'll need these variables later in the function.

Currently, I'm wrapping the entire assignment with parentheses:

```
async function myFunction() {
  let query, variables;
  try {
    ({ query, variables } = await giveMeVariables()) // Here...
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("An error ocurred");
  }

  console.log("QUERY", query);
  console.log("VARIABLES", variables);
}

function giveMeVariables () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ query: "hi", variables: "there" });
  });
}
```

Looking on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax): "The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration." Is this the preferred way of handling try/catch blocks with destructuring, or is there a better approach?

Also, how would you type this in Typescript? Would you have to type the initial variable as undefined/your expected result?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. You're writing about a function that doesn't exist in your question. There maybe a better way to design your code. Is `giveMeVariables` an async process?

Comment: OP I don't see what's wrong with the code as posted. Questions about "the best way" are generally frowned upon, because it's a matter of opinion and circumstance. If your code works, what's the problem?

Comment: Added a more full example, per your recommendation @Andy. And Pointy, you may be right... This syntax just appears odd, and I was wondering if there is a standard way of handling this because it seems like a pretty common use case. Perhaps this is the standard way! If so, will close.

Comment: 'Looks odd' seems super subjective. Are you worried people will not understand that code? If yes, maybe do go for Merdy's solution.

Comment: I was more wondering about what is considered best practice, but it seems that my solution is fine as-is. I'm going to close the question. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you're not returning anything from `myFunction`. I would return the data immediately from that function, and `await` it, and then log it.

```js
function giveMeVariables() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ query: "hi", variables: "there" });
  });
}

async function myFunction() {
  try {
    return giveMeVariables();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("An error ocurred");
  }
}

(async() => {
  const { query, variables } = await myFunction();
  console.log("QUERY", query);
  console.log("VARIABLES", variables);
})();
```

Comment: This is also what I do.  I split the try/catch into a separate function that wraps the call that might throw.  Then the destructuring statement can be made without involving a try/catch.  If you try to mix the two, you will be forced to declare all the properties from the destructuring outside of the try/catch block and type them explicitly.

Comment: Interesting, so essentially you could wrap your asynchronous call in an IIFE, in order to destructure at the top level. That would help you avoid having to statically type it yourself. Cool approach.

Comment: Depending on what `myFunction` actually does you can probably eliminate it altogether and use `try/catch` in the main async function and just get the data directly from `giveMeVariables` - cuts out the middleman.

Answer (score -2):

It's unreal, you can use var, but its a bad practice, so:

```
let query, variables;
try {
  const vars = giveMeVariables()
  query = vars.query
  variables = vars.variables
} catch (err) {
  console.log("An error occured");
}

console.log("QUERY", query);
console.log("VARIABLES", variables);
```

Comment: I don't see how this is an improvement at all. The destructuring in the OP does exactly the same thing, and it's more concise.

Comment: @Pointy it's a subjective question with a subjective answer. It's pointless to argue what's 'better', it's just different.